# Unity2D: implementing a running effect to my character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to achieve the same effect done Knuckles does in the new game Sonic mania, the effect can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrPky7eUV00) (2:18 - 2:25). So far I duplicated my main player and lowered the duplicated players alpha so that it looks a bit transparent, I also added the script below on the duplicated player to give the duplicated player some distance to the original player; however I wasn't quite sure how I can make the duplicated players slowly return the original player when the player isn't moving! I attempt using animation but it didn't look as good as what was shown in the video, I also tired to shorten the distance over Time.deltaTime however it still didn't look effective! Is there a better way of attempting the same effect shown in the video?? Thank you :)

```
public GameObject Player;
public float distance = 0.75f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    distance = 0.42f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.position = (transform.position - Player.transform.position).normalized * distance + Player.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: This is how I see it and is probably not enough for a full answer: It's probably the easiest to save the location and state of animation 'xxx' milliseconds. If you want 3 shadows you could use 3 slots. Pop the oldest one, push a new one to the front and redraw those with their alpha. You should probably pay attention to draw the original in the front. Watch the video frame by frame (use ',' and '.' while the video is paused to move a single frame) to see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TrailRenderer.
Here's the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html

You can activate it during the run effect and deactivate it otherwise.